# When CLSCompliant(true) , Operators should not be overloaded C#?

Tags: c#, c#-2.0

When CLSCompliant(true) , one of the basic rule : "Operators should not be overloaded".
Please let me know, Is the above statement is True / False. Explain the reason behind.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2sk3x8a7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CLS` stands for `Common Language Specification`. The thing is that `CLS` is a subset of `IL` features which is supported by all .NET languages. In short, not every .NET language supports operator overloading. That's why it is considered by the compiler as not `CLS compliant`.

**Update**
For example VB.NET does not support operators overloading.

Consider the following example:

```
public struct DateTime 
{
   public static TimeSpan operator -(DateTime t1, DateTime t2) { }
   public static TimeSpan Subtract(DateTime t1, DateTime t2) { }
}
```

In C# you can do the following:

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime();
DateTime dt3 = dt2 - dt1;
```

In VB.NET you are not allowed to do that. In VB.NET you will use

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime();
DateTime dt3 = dt2.Subtract(dt1);
```

Comment: Why NOT every .NET language supports operator overloading? Example.Please

Comment: Dim dt1 As ConsoleApplication2.DateTime() 
        Dim dt2 As ConsoleApplication2.DateTime() 
        Dim dt3 As ConsoleApplication2.DateTime() 
        dt3 = dt2 - dt1 <br>
Displaying Error : Operator '-' is not defined for types '1-dimensional array of ConsoleApplication2.DateTime' and '1-dimensional array of ConsoleApplication2.DateTime'.<br><br>

ConsoleApplication2.DateTime - where that struct was defined<br>

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is quite old, but I'm pretty sure it's not correct.  Operator overloading is CLS Compliant.  It's legitimate to put an operator overload in a public interface in a .NET assembly, it's just difficult to use it from VB.NET which doesn't support the simple syntax.

Consider the following C# code.  It is marked as CLS compliant.  On a build the compiler warns that the two public fields that differ by case (MyTestField/myTestField) are not CLS compliant.  However, it doesn't warn about the operator overload, which it accepts as OK.

```
using System;
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int MyTestField;
        public int myTestField;
        public static int operator +(Class1 lhs, Class1 rhs) => lhs.MyTestField + rhs.MyTestField;
    }
}
```

The reason is the overload **can** be used from a language without operator overloading such as VB.NET.  The C# compiler creates an op_Addition method in the IL, and this can be called directly from VB.NET.

If I take the second myTestField out, and then build and reference my class library from a VB.NET application then the following code works fine.  It calls the + operator from VB.NET:

C#

```
using System;
[assembly: CLSCompliant(true)]

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public int MyTestField;
        public static int operator +(Class1 lhs, Class1 rhs) => lhs.MyTestField + rhs.MyTestField;
    }
}
```

VB.NET

```
Imports ClassLibrary1

Module Program
    Sub Main()
        Dim c As Class1 = New Class1 With {.MyTestField = 1}
        Console.Write(Class1.op_Addition(c, c))
    End Sub
End Module
```

The [Microsoft design guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/operator-overloads) discuss this: 'Many languages do not support operator overloading. For this reason, it is recommended that types that overload operators include a secondary method with an appropriate domain-specific name that provides equivalent functionality.'